# New window in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two html pages. `web.html` and `addroute.html`. They are made using bootstrap. The angularjs script has two controllers in it `webctrl` and `addctrl`. I have a button in `web.html`. When I click on button in `web.html` a new window opens `addroute.html` I need to change the button name in `addroute.html` using angularjs. The getelementbyid is not working. I need to use this getelementbyid procedure. Please help me

> web.html

```
<body ng-controller='webctrl'>
<div id="content">
    <button id="share" name="share" class="btn btn-info btn-cust" ng-click="submit()" style="display: block;">CLICK TO ADDROUTE</button>
</div>

</body>
```

> addroute.html

```
<body ng-controller='addctrl'>
<div id="content">
    <p>Content = {{msg}}</p>
    <button id="subscribe" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary btn-cust" style="display: block;"></button>
</div>
</body>
```

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('webctrl', function ($scope, $window) {

$scope.submit = function () {

   $window.open('addroute.html', '_self');
        }
 })

app.controller('addctrl', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.msg = "Welcome";
    var btn = angular.element(document.getElementById('subscribe'));
    btn.textContent = "HHHHH";

   })
```

Answer (score 1):

In `addroute.html`

```
<button id="subscribe" name="subscribe"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-cust" style="display: block;">
  {{textContent}}
</button>
```

In controller

```
$scope.textContent = "HHHH";
```

Comment: Can we access the button using getelementbyid. I want this method because i was trying to load google maps when button is clicked in web.html

Comment: try angular.element(document.querySelector('#subscribe'));

Answer (score 0):

> web.html

```
  <body ng-controller='webctrl'>
<div id="content">
    <button id="share" name="share" class="btn btn-info btn-cust" ng-click="submit()" style="display: block;">CLICK TO ADDROUTE</button>
</div>

</body>
```

> addroute.html

```
<body ng-controller='addctrl'>
<div id="content">
    <p>Content = {{msg}}</p>
    <button id="subscribe" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary btn-cust" style="display: block;">{{btnName}}</button>
</div>
</body>
```

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('webctrl', function ($scope, $window) {

$scope.submit = function () {

   $window.open('addroute.html', '_self');
        }
 })

app.controller('addctrl', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.msg = "Welcome";

    $scope.btnName = "CLICK TO WEB";
   })
```